# Changing the name of the Page alias

Tags: url, alias, kentico

In Kentico 8.2 the sub-page in the URL is misspelled. The Name Path is spelled correctly.

I see that under Pages > Properties > URLs there is a place to change the alias name. Will correcting the spelling here affect anything drastic change in the website (say, in the code)?  I'd be inclined to say No, but I wanted another opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking of you make the modification/update Kentico will keep an alias of the misspelling so if anyone has reference to it, they can go to that bad URL and be redirected.

If there is custom code looking for that misspelled URL then it will have to be corrected but as you stayed probably not.

If webparts or widgets refer to that misspelled URL in the  path property, they will have to be corrected.  You will notice this right away on pages of they are referencing that misspelled URL because your content won't show up.

Comment: Looks like everything worked just fine. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @jacqueshock be sure to upvote any answers you find helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the page-alias it will add the old alias to the list of page aliases (ie. old links to the page should still work).

Are you specifically using that page-alias in code anywhere to identify the page? 
similar to:

```
var aliasPath = tree.SelectNodes()
                .WhereLike("DocumentName", "Tutorials").FirstObject.NodeAliasPath;
```

but referring to the alias field instead.

Would the page be linked in any wysiwyg editors?  I'm not sure if behind the scenes kentico would use page-alias in this instance or the document guid. Although if you retained the old misspelled alias then existing links should work.

Comment: Looks like the only place where the misspelling occurs is in the link or href. (This is just one example.) 

`<form method="post" action="/Goverment.aspx" id="form">`